# Local network with router ping works in only one direction, no incoming packets other way

Tags: networking, router, ping

I'm trying to understand routing and today one thing surprised me. On my local network with wi-fi router I have two laptops connected to it. Ip of one  is 192.168.1.8, other is 192.168.56.1 (both DHCP-ed as far as I understand), internet working on both. Ping from 56.1 to 1.8 works, from 1.8 to 56.1 does not. Ping like cnn.com on 1.8 works.

It's Windows 7 both. I've read now on firewall blocking ping, but even when I blocked incoming ICMPv4 on 1.8, ping from 56.1 failed, but I could see incoming packets count increase in network status (I've pinged with large packets), whereas on 56.1 I do not see incoming packets during ping from 1.8. Why can't I send packets to 56.1?

Comment: What subnet mask and default gateway is configured on each laptop?

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely that the DHCP server running on your router would assign IP addresses from `192.168.0.0/16` range and that it would choose addresses so different from each other.

My guess is: you've missed that the laptop with `192.168.56.1` actually has one more IP address which belongs to the the `192.168.1.0/24` network and which really was assigned by the DHCP server.

This would also explain why laptop with `192.168.56.1` can ping `192.168.1.8` - its routing table contains route for the `192.168.1.0/24` network because it is connected to it. However laptop with `192.168.1.8` is not aware of any `192.168.56.0/24` network. You would have to manually configure new route on this laptop that allows access to the `192.168.56.0/24` network via the IP on the second laptop - the very IP you don't know at this time.

Check the `Details...` option in `Status` of your `Adapters` in `Network Connections` section of Windows settings. This should allow you to find the IP address you're missing. Alternatively you can login to your router to identify IPs of your laptops.

Comment: Your guess was right. I was working on other issue when I noted the thing. Now I looked at computers again and noted that 56.1 is actually VirtualBox ip, not interface to router, I have not done work on that notebook for long time and forgot it may have something that other computer did not have installed.